# Reading lines from a pdb file

Tags: fortran, protein-database

I want to read only those lines that contains "ATOM" as the first word and write in a file using a Fortran code.
I have tried to write a code but was unable to read that specific lines containing word "ATOM" only. I hope someone can help me in this regard.

[image]

Comment: This is not a code writing service - please show us what you have done so far and explain what is wrong. That said googling "read pdb fortran" produces many hits - do any of those solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

you need something like this:

```
character*4 word

character*256 line

read(filename,1000) word,line

1000 format(A4,A256)

if (word .eq. 'ATOM') then

     write(10,1000) word,line
```